# Nesting loops in javascript

Tags: javascript

I think the code below is correct:

The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.

If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.

The call to the function lookUpProfile with the arguments "Kristian" and "lastName" should return the value "Vos" but it is not.

Some idea where is wrong?

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

    for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<contacts[i].length;j++){
            if(contacts[i][0]===firstName && contacts[i][j].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                  return contacts[i][j];
                  }
            }
        }
    }



// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

Comment: `for(var j=0;j<contacts[i];j++){` -- it's wrong there

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the second for loop is checking for a property `contacts[i].length` that simply doesn't exists. Objects don't have a `.length` property, only Arrays.

You don't need a second for loop to cycle all the properties, you can just check the firstName and then check if the property you want is there, then return it.

`for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if(contacts[i]['firstName']===firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
  }`

Should be what you want.

---

If you want to cycle all the object properties you should use a `for in` loop like this:

`for(var key in contacts[i]){
  //place your check here using contacts[i][key] the get the value for the key
}`

Edit: added `for in` example

Comment: Yes, I treated it like an array with sub-arrays instead of a array of objects. Anyway, though your first code is better it doesn't work either.

Comment: Working fine here.http://jsbin.com/kebenabezu/edit?js,console

Try calling your function in the console panel

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it works. What happened is that as a task for freeCodeCamp, there were another two conditions I had put wrong. Once these last ones are well coded all the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem only with two lines of code in your lookup-function:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  var contact = contacts.find((c) => c.firstName === firstName);
  return contact.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? contact[prop] : null;
}
```

Try it out with my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benjib/dbrz1xp1/).